# Google Maps v3 Grey Box with React

Tags: google-maps-api-3, reactjs

Hey guys I am trying to add a google map to a react project and I am getting a grey box with no errors. Any idea why. Here's the code:

```
componentDidMount: function(){


    function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: 37.7749300, lng: -122.4194200},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
    };
        initMap(); 

 }// end of cdm;
});
```

Comment: I noticed that the box renders when I stretch the screen. I tried google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}); but it didnt fix the problem

Comment: Same answer for your same problem ^^ ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779489/rendering-a-google-map-without-react-google-map/43624533#43624533

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using document.getElementByID('map'). Is that a node inside this component you are trying to render the google.maps container?

This should really look like

```
function renderMap() {
    // map node
    var mapNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.map);
    new google.maps.Map(mapNode, {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: 37.7749300, lng: -122.4194200},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}
```

You need to add react-dom as a dependency.